# Different DF in lme

Tags: lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

I have a data set with the two explanatory variables that represent the same variable but comes from two different climatic models thus they have slightly different variability. There are the exactly the same experiments in data set and the same dependent variable.
I do simple models that differ just by this explanatory variable

```
library(nlme)    
mod1 <- lme(H ~ G5a, random = ~1|Trial, data = df)
    mod2 <- lme(H~ G5b, random = ~1|Trial, data = df)
```

I wonder why do I get different number of Degrees of freedom for explanatory variable

```
summary(mod1)                  
                   Value Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
    (Intercept) 69.94093  40.66307 8848 1.720011  0.0855
    G5a          0.22067   0.03636  535 6.068325  0.0000
    
 

    Correlation: 
         (Intr)
G5a          -0.969

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-14.63509753  -0.38219265   0.01420969   0.44639253   8.45121509 

Number of Observations: 9385
Number of Groups: 537 

summary(mod2)
                Value Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 146.28353  32.34715 8847 4.522300       0
G5b           0.15259   0.02883 8847 5.293469       0
 Correlation: 
    (Intr)
G5b           -0.951

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-14.62832784  -0.38302328   0.01383814   0.44830083   8.44690339 

Number of Observations: 9385
Number of Groups: 537
```

There are no NA's in H, G5a, G5b. Trial is the same, H is the same for both models.The same happens for the `library(lme4)`

Differences between explanatory variables
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it me a data type issue? Isn't one coded as factors, or something?

Comment: No it is not à vase. Both explanatory variabels are numeric.

Comment: Can you include in your post the entire output of the summary() function applied to each of the two models? We need to know how many observations and groups the model summaries report.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, added

Comment: Is it the variability in the explanatory variables? If  `G5a` is (mostly) constant within `Trial` and `G5b` isn't, the df for one will be close to # Trials and the other will be close to #  observations

Comment: @ThomasLumley, No it is not that. The variables are the same within `Trial` (I added quick box plot)

Comment: To rule out the explanation provided by @ThomasLumley, you would need to plot the range (i.e., min and max) of each of your 2 problematic variables versus trial number.  It’s not enough to plot one variable against the other.  We need to see whether the min and max values are really close to each other across trials for one of the variables.

Comment: Other things to try just out of curiosity: scale your predictor variable in each model by applying the scale() function to it and then fit the model; change the model fitting engine from lmer() in lme4 to, say, gamlss() in gamlss.

Comment: For an alternative fitting engine, can you try the brms() function in the brms() package?

Comment: There seems to be some problem with `mod2` in that the total DF associated with the fixed effects greatly exceeds the number of observations. In contrast, in `mod1` those DF add up to 9383 with 9385 observations, which makes sense. Did `mod2` not converge to a solution and exit with a warning, perhaps?

Comment: The trial is represented by just one value, the variable value is the same for all observation in the trial, at least should be

Comment: I run the same models in SAS, lme and lmer and I got the same coefficient in all of them but other DF. I am glad that at least the results of the coefficient estimation are comprehensive and the issue of DF is beyond my scope in statistics.